# Nvidia Series 10XX on Mac OS

Tags: video, gpu, osx

Does anybody use any Nvidia card (1050, 1060, 1070, 1080)on a MacPro 5,1 or else version of Mac?
I did not find any benchmark on Nvidia cards on Mac, the "sheet" of Blender developpers using cards, shows very different results according to the platform and the OS used.
Is it worth having two cards (like 2x1060-6GO)?
I've heard Blender will not add or manage 2x6GO like it would manage 12GO on a single card?
Thanks for answers

Comment: When using multiple cards, vRAM is not added to a common pool: each GPU card works with its own memory. If you use multiple cards with different amounts of vRAM, then the amount of memory available for rendering will be limited to the card that has the least. Even in cards that have multiple GPUs built in, the memory available for each one is not shared.

Comment: What's your hardware situation? Do you own a Mac already or are you looking to buy one? If you don't have one yet you might consider the recently updated Mac Pro with an external GPU connected by Thunderbolt 2 (or 3 with an adapter). You can do this with a [Bizon Box](https://bizon-tech.com).

Comment: I've one macPro late 2006 32GO

Comment: But my videocard died...So I decided to buy a Westmere 2010

Comment: Mac Pro 5,1
Quad-Core Intel Xeon
2,8 GHz
Cache de niveau 2 (par cœur) : 256 Ko
Cache de niveau 3 : 8 Mo
Mémoire : 32 Go
Vitesse d’interconnexion du processeur : 4,8 GT/s

Comment: What I'd like to do is to take the ATI Radeon HD 5770 from my new MacPro and install it in the old MacPro 1,1.

Comment: In the future I'd like to upgrade with 2x3,46 Ghz 12 cores, 32GO more ram and SSD card

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I did not know it was possible to connect an external GPU with thunderbolt. I'm gonna study this interesting way.

Answer (score 1):

The GTX 10XX cards were not supported under OS X until just this past week. So benchmark data will be hard to find. For now.

Also, if you haven't already, study up on using newer Nvidia cards in the classic "cheesegrater" Mac Pro's, there are some caveats, especially if the card has not be reflashed. (off the shelf PC cards will work, but you won't have a startup splash and you may need to switch the monitor to a Mac card or use SSH to update the driver after installing OS updates)

Cycles can render across multiple cards, however the scene must copied in its entirety to each card, so you don't get to "add" the VRAM amounts. See: [Does Blender support dual-GPU rendering if the two GPUs aren't the same?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68257/does-blender-support-dual-gpu-rendering-if-the-two-gpus-arent-the-same)

Comment: My idea was to put 2x1070 or 1060. But I don't really understand how Blender manages cycle with 2x6GO (especially for volumetric, dynamics, particles...). So if each card has the entire scene, how do they share the render or bake? I think I make a misunderstanding between the CUDA for the calcul and the Vram what for?

Comment: @tontonlolo Each card works independently on a separate region of the render. Because Cycles is a global illumination render, each card needs the entire scene even though each is only working on a different portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but thought I'd post some GTX1060 6GB results:

[image]

Render time is about 63 seconds.
That's the blenchmark scene rendered by hitting F12 (blenchmark addon throws errors when I hit the benchmark button)
Might also be worth noting that I'm running High Sierra, and on a Hackintosh.

Lastly, CPU+GPU rendering also works, causing render time to cut in exactly half.