# Anyone using dual 5700xt GPU's?

Tags: gpu

I currently run a single 5700xt, which has great performance, but just wondering if dual 5700xt's would work well in Blender to improve render times and viewport performance?

I'd appreciate any help you guys can give.

Thanks!

Jon

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68257/does-blender-support-dual-gpu-rendering-if-the-two-gpus-arent-the-same/

Comment: Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - much appreciated!