# GTX+Radeon in Blender - It's possible?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, opengl, opencl

I'm a long-time Blender user and my projects are becoming more and more complex and I was thinking in buying a new GPU. Now I'm using a GTX 970 V1 Windforce and a Intel Xeon X5660. A lot of people suggested me to buy a HD7870 Triple Vent since I will use this machine also as Hackintosh, is it possible to use the GTX and the Radeon together? I heard that you can combine the two by using OpenCL or OpenGL

Comment: Hi and Welcome. Unfortunately questions about hardware are off-topic... Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68257/does-blender-support-dual-gpu-rendering-if-the-two-gpus-arent-the-same

Comment: Ah okay... do you know where I can ask this question?

Comment: Reddit, Blenderartists. Not sure whether that's worth it, for cycles you want nvidia anyway...

Comment: Can you suggest me a cheap nvidia card?

Comment: I was thinking in a GTX 770

Comment: Depends on your budget: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html